# 自分のデータと世界地図上の情報をリンクさせるのにCartopyは適切な手段でしょうか。

Tags: pyside

[python](/questions/tagged/python)を用いて、世界地図上と自分のアプリのデータをリンクさせたいです。

例えば、ある国のある都市を世界地図上のマウスポインタ等の操作でアクセスを行い、そこの都市をクリックすれば、対応する自分のデータが出てくる。あるいは、自分のデータからその都市へとアクセスする。相互リンクを築きたいです。地図はできるだけ詳細なものがあればいいなと思っていますが、ツールとしては、[cartopy](/questions/tagged/cartopy)を考えています。
都市と言いましても、厳密なピンポイントのアクセスでは無くて、**大体の地域や地帯**で構いません。見たところ、`Google map`のように、そこまで表示できるようには思えないからです。

しかし、この[cartopy](/questions/tagged/cartopy)は、科学計算用のライブラリで、気象情報等を計測する目的で作成されているようであり、[matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib)と連携されて使用されることを念頭においているようです。

私のように、自分のデータと世界地図上の位置座標をリンクさせたいという目的で、使うことはできますか？

[python](/questions/tagged/python)で世界地図上の様々な位置情報とアクセスできるライブラリはありませんか？また、その世界地図上にデータを埋め込むことが出来るのであれば、それを行いたいです。[cartopy](/questions/tagged/cartopy)はデータを**可視化**する目的であって、いわゆる[userｰinterface](/questions/tagged/user%ef%bd%b0interface)向きではありませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cartopy は、地図上に天気図等の画像を作成するために使うのは便利ですが、あくまで画像なのでインターラクティブな操作はできません。インターラクティブなことをするのであれば、d3.js等のJavaScriptのライブラリーを使った方が便利だと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`Qt`で`JavaScript`を使うことが出来るようなので、`JavaScript`学んでみるのもいいかなと思ってたんで、ちょうどいい機会なきがします。`d3.js`調べてみます。